# Is there an R function to do multiple correlations rather than rewritting the code block

Tags: r, correlation

I'm currently having to subset data in multiple ways to extract the data I need to do a correlation and identify if there is a relationship between the same metals of the groups.

```
Group1 <- subset(Data_Set, subset = Data_Set$Sample == "1")
Group1A <- subset(Group1, subset = Group1$Sample_Type == "A")
GroupX <- subset(Data_Set, subset = Data_Set$Sample == "X")
GroupX<- subset(GroupX, Sample_ID %in% Group1A$Sample_ID )
cor.test(Group1A$Pb,GroupX$Pb, method = "kendall")
```

*ID is used to match between groups*

However, this is very inefficient. I have in total 6 groups which have subgroups (between 1-6) composed of 1-40 samples and I looking to see if there is a relationship between any of these groups and GroupX. Is there a function to speed this up.

The output would be something along the lines of:

```
Pb                 T     p-value    tau                   
Group1A~GroupX    340     0.001    0.5902
Group1B~GroupX    435     0.03     0.2344
.....
Group6C~GroupX    344     0.001    0.4566
```

And this would be repeated for 5 other metals

I was thinking a standard correlation matrix but this does correlations between metals within a group.

Thanks!

EDIT: Sample data as requested

```
structure(list(Sample = c("2", "2", "2", "2", "X", "2", "2", 
"2", "2", "2", "2", "X", "2", "2", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "X", 
"5", "5", "3", "3", "X", "3", "3", "X", "4", "4"), Sample_ID = c("DC001", 
"DC001", "DC001", "DC001", "DC001", "DC001", "DC001", "DC002", 
"DC002", "DC002", "DC002", "DC002", "DC002", "DC002", "DC003", 
"DC003", "DC003", "DC003", "DC003", "DC003", "DC003", "DC003", 
"DC004", "DC004", "DC004", "DC005", "DC005", "DC005", "DC006", 
"DC006"), Sample_Type = c("A", "D", "E", "F", "X", "I", "J", 
"A", "D", "E", "F", "X", "I", "J", "A", "B", "D", "E", "F", "X", 
"I", "J", "C", "F", "X", "C", "F", "X", "A", "D"), Co = c(0, 
0.204473214269861, 0, 0.50977856054987, 0.262230521160956, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.465855303428853, 0.229502158969648, 0.214970121592712, 
0.588126362402572, 0, 0.0906122639531158, 0.229838105464066, 
0, 0.240533898070871, 4.77802122014029, 0.47537095149254, 0.384495379166814, 
0.00135414270258444, 0.458235177876183, 0.412977043885698, 0.187579567424379, 
0.317854941692133, 0.0271598068567071, 0, 0.293328743450483), 
    Ni = c(2.32894078024542, 0, 2.75976812547636, 2.35251746719724, 
    0.351631195258774, 1.25476391714642, 0.0586626807902249, 
    0, 2.31716731851309, 0, 4.03426936736104, 0.414520597983989, 
    2.69897385721456, 0.781651988488391, 1.48260693680732, 1.59083944326126, 
    0.944038748319438, 3.06889126279262, 1.69552165261712, 0.849220149877567, 
    1.75387912556474, 0, 0.333762199305291, 1.66187141150986, 
    0.735834552887327, 3.72419677755011, 1.27862769479216, 0.264762516047524, 
    1.84288031704096, 1.8828793053893), Cu = c(16.6696573471153, 
    21.377014252538, 16.4581203986139, 6.49438237470201, 1.57054125960644, 
    5.67180974109468, 23.5835333332964, 38.6483288663375, 15.2589198442198, 
    21.9746392829346, 7.09307693625389, 0.967127488045321, 6.32542891436958, 
    16.1173426649179, 11.2222721930992, 8.42093833910001, 11.1332246071585, 
    16.7442343774396, 10.8140656299147, 14.2632807636599, 5.35502290473828, 
    7.29141216675894, 2.53789491234011, 16.5791995430022, 1.00648647764661, 
    26.6313784234462, 0.0413060789264422, 0.656674377606213, 
    3.98095036332964, 6.17760205144632), Zn = c(76.5281110975817, 
    2652.50181007495, 1007.00556337852, 206.99812727191, 640.15733114957, 
    484.221162531697, 3718.61286231799, 131.574098527507, 9826.49966864988, 
    1827.75831773692, 557.015412652748, 850.519284594127, 955.085171501707, 
    3039.23169926716, 117.947177178762, 65.7886442827721, 78.1092625035093, 
    253.691311074245, 980.544294923672, 506.400193234096, 1110.92409209043, 
    902.659801267825, 284.143460051779, 991.762202132739, 899.71040333897, 
    1686.99915717559, 27.0835877755038, 956.364728487396, 142.167067778216, 
    1012.61495002819), As = c(0, 0, 1.91185052013389, 1.32808264279786, 
    0.141039242323703, 1.74872331719823, 0.1065340816859, 0.812367854870543, 
    0, 0.797230094696634, 2.38925992872935, 0.305621793073037, 
    0.664951374730799, 0, 0, 0, 2.52051964809224, 0, 0, 0.392178178336116, 
    0, 3.08334159340895, 2.32108729394528, 1.62081021652742, 
    0.171200134084414, 6.19125023716284, 4.43213876523911, 0.289386770990403, 
    0.313331113399545, 6.41607755268465), Cd = c(8.22465741493669, 
    22.6126042664945, 34.0150873273517, 13.5844058876617, 5.22665850051452, 
    24.0465414683255, 109.478598702669, 15.1992477278811, 169.517190223851, 
    75.2983940524065, 34.5230481628261, 3.75297525105592, 45.6178498733986, 
    247.435132822196, 2.10793502840313, 1.47647473271431, 0.0848090794945706, 
    2.98717760781629, 3.13384011407655, 5.31936421369202, 3.73593799828465, 
    5.36310372449921, 0.298562637256625, 1.82673831232711, 3.78462211601718, 
    8.0628550389363, 0.138799690323038, 1.32275598609847, 0.285061500560821, 
    0.635235209786838), Pb = c(0.922803462498185, 5.13959353157866, 
    1.9525414480789, 0, 2.5902978681043, 1.21865949505257, 7.09067896476338, 
    0, 3.89524247237658, 0.354938950934777, 2.64634863087263, 
    0.356658949506862, 1.25701617111933, 4.18799241835111, 0, 
    0.807369345092201, 0.0263264119388502, 0, 3.32333444396018, 
    76.7555925603143, 0.613522400825461, 0, 1.72315815094652, 
    3.21414903849599, 1.03802696495681, 1.73176109371547, 0.72736174943572, 
    0.23309888503164, 12.8688959655249, 33.2486209089115)), row.names = c(NA, 
-30L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(Data_Set)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(Data_Set, 30))`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas done!

Comment: Just as a note: in your example data, there is no `Group1` etc. People who try to reproduce what you have as your example need to figure out what your data look like and adjust your code accordingly, which is not ideal. Would also be nice to have the output of `head(Data_Set)` in the formatted way in the question to make it easier to see what you try to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know @coffeinjunky I've edited it so it should work. But let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: I keep looking at the data and can't see a way of getting to correlations.  I can easily see a way of getting to a comparison between the groups of mean or median levels of any of the metals.  Can't tell from your sample data what's going on.

Comment: RHT is your research question whether for example lead (Pb) levels vary significantly between these various groups and the baseline group "X"?

Comment: When I execute your code, I am left with groups that have no observations in them.

Comment: @coffeinjunky I changed Group2 to GroupX, in the full dataset it works. The dataset I have provided is just a sample dataset to understand the current layout.

Comment: @ChuckP The research question would be "Do Pb concentrations in group1 have a significant relationship with Pb concentrations in groupX". Once you separate the groups into their respective dataframes you can do a cor.test between them. Of which the result it this `Kendall's rank correlation tau

data:  Group1A$Pb and GroupX$Pb
z = 1.2632, p-value = 0.2065
alternative hypothesis: true tau is not equal to 0
sample estimates:
      tau 
0.5270463 `

Comment: Okay, I finally figured out what your data looks like and what you're trying to do.  I'll come back to this tomorrow or Sunday meantime perhaps someone else can help you faster.  By the way how many rows in your real data?

Comment: Great, thanks @ChuckP . The real data has approx 1000 rows and growing.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that get's you exactly what you want.  It looks a little long and forbidding but I've tried to make it easy to follow and to expand and bullet it proof to missing observations, and NAs etc..  I also have a brute force solution that does **all* the correlations then removes all those you don't need.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
library(broom)

# made up data set that is similar to yours but with missing rows and NAs
set.seed(2020)
Data_Set <-
  data.frame(
    Sample = c(rep("X", times = 10), rep("2", times = 20), "X", "2"),
    Sample_ID = c(rep(c("DC001", "DC002", "DC003", "DC004", "DC005", "DC006", "DC007", "DC008", "DC009", "DC010"), times = 3), "DC011", "DC012"),
    Sample_Type = c(rep("X", times = 10), rep("A", times = 10), rep("D", times = 10), "X", "A"),
    Co = runif(32, 0, 5),
    Ni = runif(32, 0, 4.1),
    Cu = runif(32, 0, 39),
    Zn = runif(32, 27, 9800),
    As = runif(32, 0, 6),
    Cd = runif(32, 0, 247),
    Pb = runif(32, 0, 78)
  )

Data_Set[15,5] <- NA

# Data_Set

# Collapse Sample and Sample_Type into one Group variable
Data_Set <-
  Data_Set %>%
  mutate(Group = str_c(Sample, Sample_Type)) %>%
  select(Group, everything())

# Pull out Group XX (our baseline) and relabel
# the metals with an _X on the end

JustGroupX <-
  Data_Set %>%
  filter(Group == "XX") %>%
  mutate(Group = "X") %>%
  rename(Co_X = Co,
         Ni_X = Ni,
         Cu_X = Cu,
         Zn_X = Zn,
         As_X = As,
         Cd_X = Cd,
         Pb_X = Pb) %>%
  select(-Group, -Sample, -Sample_Type)

# a df with no XX
AllNotX <-
  Data_Set %>%
  filter(Group != "XX")

# Make a list of DF's by Group
ListofGroupDFs <-
  AllNotX %>%
  split(.$Group)

# glimpse(ListofGroupDFs)

ListofGroupDFs <- map(ListofGroupDFs, ~ inner_join(., JustGroupX, by = "Sample_ID"))

# this part is inelegant since it simply repeats the same code for each metal
# I'll try and make it prettier another day

CoResults <-
  map_dfr(ListofGroupDFs,
          ~ tidy(cor.test(.$Co, .$Co_X, method = "kendall")),
          .id = "ComparedwithX") %>%
  mutate(Metal = "Co")
CoResults$Metal <- "Co"

NiResults <-
  map_dfr(ListofGroupDFs,
          ~ tidy(cor.test(.$Ni, .$Ni_X, method = "kendall")),
          .id = "ComparedwithX") %>%
  mutate(Metal = "Ni")
NiResults$Metal <- "Ni"

CuResults <-
  map_dfr(ListofGroupDFs,
          ~ tidy(cor.test(.$Cu, .$Cu_X, method = "kendall")),
          .id = "ComparedwithX") %>%
  mutate(Metal = "Cu")
CuResults$Metal <- "Cu"

ZnResults <-
  map_dfr(ListofGroupDFs,
          ~ tidy(cor.test(.$Zn, .$Zn_X, method = "kendall")),
          .id = "ComparedwithX") %>%
  mutate(Metal = "Zn")
ZnResults$Metal <- "Zn"

AsResults <-
  map_dfr(ListofGroupDFs,
          ~ tidy(cor.test(.$As, .$As_X, method = "kendall")),
          .id = "ComparedwithX") %>%
  mutate(Metal = "As")
AsResults$Metal <- "As"

CdResults <-
  map_dfr(ListofGroupDFs,
          ~ tidy(cor.test(.$Cd, .$Cd_X, method = "kendall")),
          .id = "ComparedwithX") %>%
  mutate(Metal = "Cd")
CdResults$Metal <- "Cd"

PbResults <-
  map_dfr(ListofGroupDFs,
        ~ tidy(cor.test(.$Pb, .$Pb_X, method = "kendall")),
        .id = "ComparedwithX") %>%
  mutate(Metal = "Pb")
PbResults$Metal <- "Pb"

MyResults <- rbind(CoResults,
                   NiResults,
                   CuResults,
                   ZnResults,
                   AsResults,
                   CdResults,
                   PbResults)

MyResults <-
  MyResults %>%
  rename(tau = estimate, T = statistic) %>%
  select(Metal,
         ComparedwithX,
         tau,
         T,
         p.value)

MyResults
#> # A tibble: 14 x 5
#>    Metal ComparedwithX     tau     T p.value
#>    <chr> <chr>           <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1 Co    2A             0.0222    23   1    
#>  2 Co    2D             0.0667    24   0.862
#>  3 Ni    2A             0.444     26   0.119
#>  4 Ni    2D            -0.111     20   0.727
#>  5 Cu    2A            -0.2       18   0.484
#>  6 Cu    2D             0.0667    24   0.862
#>  7 Zn    2A             0.289     29   0.291
#>  8 Zn    2D             0.156     26   0.601
#>  9 As    2A            -0.0222    22   1    
#> 10 As    2D            -0.422     13   0.108
#> 11 Cd    2A             0.2       27   0.484
#> 12 Cd    2D            -0.0667    21   0.862
#> 13 Pb    2A            -0.333     15   0.216
#> 14 Pb    2D             0.2       27   0.484
```